# Store and handle MySQL Results

Tags: php, html, mysql

So, I'm learning **PHP** and **MySQL**, but I have run into a little problem here.

I do lack some information, so this will be very helpful to me =)

I do a query against my database, and get a result. This result is all my image files to be listed.

```
$fileSQL = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM content
    WHERE projID=$projectID     
");
```

So, if I want to list all my files as thumbnails on my page I do this:

```
<?php while($row = $fileSQL->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <img src="assets/<?=$row['contentFull']?>" id="thumbImg"
    onclick="document.getElementById('mainImage').src=this.src" width="110px" height="62px"/>           
<?php } ?>
```

Now, this works fine, of course. It loops through all the rows while adding a  for each of them.

However, I do have a main image too, where I need to show the first thumb in full (for this example I use `contentFull` both for thumbs and fullsize).

Now, how do I get the first row's `contentFull`, without making the while loop start from row nr.2?

And in general; what is the best way to do in these situations? Store the result to an array first, so I can access it easily, or what is the "normal" way of doing it? =)

What I need:

1. Do a query
2. Set the main image (using contentFull from the first
   image/content in my sql result)
3. Then draw all the images in the
       result to thumbnails (including the first that are already shown as
       the main image)

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if you need more information =)

Comment: OT but glad to see you are learning mysqli_* functions rather than mysql_* ones

Comment: Although negating them by not using parametrised queries

Comment: What do you mean by that allen213?

Comment: @StianBergLarsen allen213 means you should use prepared statements. More info in [the manual](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

One simple options would be to do this:

```
<?php 
$first = null;
while($row = $fileSQL->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!isset($first)) $first = $row;
    ?>
    <img src="assets/<?=$row['contentFull']?>" id="thumbImg"
    onclick="document.getElementById('mainImage').src=this.src" width="110px" height="62px"/>           
<?php } ?>
```

Now you have the first row stored in a variable to use, without having to store all the results in an array. If for some reason you want all rows stored in an array you could simply do this:

```
<?php 
$rows = array();
while($row = $fileSQL->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    //rest of code
}
?>
```

Then you could access first row by referencing `$rows[0]`

Another option would be to not use php to populate the full image. Instead use a javascript call to populate the first image.

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but I was hoping there where other ways to do it? It's not possible to simply call $row[0]['contentFull'] of some sorts, to get that dat afrom the first row of results?

Comment: If you want to do that then look into using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Or you simply have to store all rows in an array as you go through your while loop.

Comment: @Pitchinnate you don't need to have two variables, `$first` and `$first_image`, within the `if` condition just check `isset($first_image)` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could take your first picture outside the `while` loop:

```
$row = $fileSQL->fetch_assoc(); // the first picture
if($row){
  // show first image if it exists
  }

while ( $row = $fileSQL->fetch_assoc()) // etc.
```

Probably code for larger image is different than for others, so it could be reasonable. If not, consider defining a function, or use a counter (or flag like in Pitchinnate's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317527/2088851)).

Comment: but wont this skip the first row when entering the while loop? Since I've already fetched a row outside the loop?

Comment: Yes it will, so you need to handle this case in full way. If it is the same, you may write a function for this, but I was supposing you were going to show first image in different way than all the others.

Comment: You can reset the seek by using `mysqli_data_seek()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php